# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 not available

Tags: java, aes, jce

I have code in java 1.4 version there we got a new requirement like have decrypt a password from another webservice response, for that have to use AES 256 decryption, getting following exception:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1"); 

java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 not available 
at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA12275) 
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA12275) 
at ftpserver.AESEncrypter.main(AESEncrypter.java:107)
```

I tried by copying jce_policy_1-4 version jars into java home security folder still am getting the above exception.
Is there any solution in Java 1.4 without changing to 1.5 because running jboss server version 3.2.3 will not support java 1.5.

Comment: Firstly, I know of no widely used Java implementation of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 (and I looked as I found myself needing to implement PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256).  That being said, you should be able to get HmacSHA1.  Secondly, why are you using PBKDF2 to decrypt something?

Comment: Have to create SecretKeyFactory instance right to decrypt also?

Comment: If someone used PBKDF2 to hash a password it can't be "decrypted".  That's the entire point of PBKDF2

Comment: but that webservice cant change now, is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to install the Bouncy Castle cryptography *provider*.

It can be found starting from [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html). Look for PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 on the front page and you will see that it is supported.